# Import closed methods and attributes

Tags: python

I'm trying to import my class in order to use its attributes in another one. 
Is it possible to call methods of basic class for derivative one? In the basic class there are methods,which have closed methods with closed attributes inside.

Or should I open its methods and its attributes for calling them at all?
So, I would like to present you an example, pleasem help me with that? I'm lost a little bit.

**I have a basic class (1):**

```
   class Car (object):
    """Virtual car"""

   total=0

   def __init__(self,petrol=100): 
        self.__petrol=petrol

    @property
        def petrol(self):
        return self.__petrol

    @petrol.setter
    def petrol(self,new_petrol):
        self.__petrol=new_petrol
       print("The level of petrol was changed")

    def __str__(self):
         print("Car condition")
         print(" "+ self.__petrol )

    def __addPetrol(self):
         print("Welcome to petrol station!")
         addPetr=int(input("Enter quanity of litres: "))
         self.__petrol=self.petrol+addPetr
         print("Thank you for visit the OIL service!")

    def __visitSrvice(self):
       print("""
           1. pour some petrol
           2. poor some oil
              """)
       visit=int(input("Choose a turn"))
       if 1==visit :
           self.__addPetrol()

       if 2==visit :
        ..............
    def go(self):
          print("""
          1. Go on your journey
          2. Visit a service
              """)
          gg = int(input("Choose  your action"))
           if 1==gg :
              ..................
          if 2==gg :
               self.__visitSrvice()

      if __name__ == "__main__":
            print("Use modul correctly")
            input("press enter to out")
```

*Then I'm trying to import The basic class into another file, and call a function, look at,please:*

```
  import Mcar

  class Chassis_Engine(object):
        def Deterioration(self):


        def Recovering(self):
            Mcar.Car.visitService(self)

  ce=Chassis_Engine()
  ce.Recovering()
```

*Sure, I have an error, which says that:*

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "E:/car/car.py", line 11, in 
>       ce.Recovering()
>
> File "E:/car/car.py", line 8, in Recovering
>       Mcar.Car.visitService(self)
>
> AttributeError: type object 'Car' has no attribute 'visitService'

Say to me please, can I do so, if I don't want to open closed methods and atrributes? If no, how should I go? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a function called `dir` that gives you all the methods a class provides. Observe:

```
>>> class A:
...   def __hidden():
...     print('hello')
...     
>>> dir(A)
['_A__hidden', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']
```

The very first method (`_A__hidden`) is what you're looking for.

In general, there are no truly 'private' methods in Python. Instead, you can have these 'double underscore' methods, that are, however, exposed to public, although, with a *modified name*: `_ClassName__MethodName`.

Comment: Thanks, I got it, but what if I'm trying to do like this: `   def Recovering(self):  Mcar.Car.go(self) `  . Then it calls it, but I have and error,that: `AttributeError: 'Chassis_Engine' object has no attribute '_Car__in_action'`.Can you say, what I can do with that?

Comment: @X21, I don't see any method called `__in_action` in the code you posted. Also, you should use that technique _outside_ the class `Car`. You can try doing this in `Chassis_Engine.Recovering`: `Mcar.Car._Car__visitService(self)`.

Comment: I don't get ,I did like this: `Mcar.Car._Car__visitService(self)`
but its says that: `AttributeError: 'Chassis_Engine' object has no attribute '_Car__addPetrol'`. Why can't it call? It seems to me that when i write `self` in derivative class, it refers on `Chassis_Engine`, not on `Car` class

Comment: @X21, because you're passing `Chassis_Engine`'s `self` to `Mcar.Car.__visitService` somehow. I think, you shouldn't be able to do this in the first place as `Mcar.Car.__visitService` doesn't accept any arguments other than the implicit `self`. You probably have some incorrect indentation somewhere.

Comment: Oh, I did like this: `Mcar.Car._Car__visitService(Mcar.Car)` and changed in `Mcar` : `self.__addPetrol(self)` in `def __visitService(self):` and here `self.__in_action(self)` . But, please, help me the last time, if you can, now I have an error in this line  `self.petrol=self.petrol+addPetr` . It says that: `    self.petrol=self.petrol+addPetr
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'property' and 'float'`. why:((((((

Comment: @X21, you've got a setter for `self.petrol` in your class just for that purpose. BTW, properties are normally used _outside_ the class as `Car` has _direct_ access to `Car.__petrol`, so you could just use that variable instead.

Comment: whyyyyyyyy? I can't get it !! `Car.__petrol=Car.__petrol+addPetr` , it SAYS: AttributeError: type object 'Car' has no attribute '_Car__petrol'

Comment: @X21, wait, `Car.__petrol` is _different_ from `self.__petrol` that you use _inside_ the class `Car`. _Edit_: looks like you forgot to create an _instance_ of `Mcar.Car`, that should be the source of the problems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147914/discussion-between-x21-and-forcebru).